# Retrofit: How to wait for response

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have AsyncTask and the doInBackground method inside which, I sending POST request using Retrofit. My code looks like:

```
    //method of AsyncTask
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Retrofit restAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.ROOT_API_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        IConstructSecureAPI service = restAdapter.create(IConstructSecureAPI.class);
        //request
        Call<JsonElement> result = service.getToken("TestUser", "pass", "password");
        result.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

        return true;
    }
```

The problem is: Retrofit sending request asynchronously and while it, the doInBackground method returning the value. So I need to send a request in the same thread with all executions in the sequence. One by one. And returning from doInBackground occurs after the request finished. How can I send a request in the same thread using Retrofit?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `Call` class has an [`execute()`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html#execute--) method that will make your call synchronously.

`enqueue()` is explicitly for making an asychronous call.

Comment: yeah but as execute() is synchronous, its seems to be running on the main thread. In this case execute() is the right answer because already, the poster is working on a background thread and execute() will be on that thread.

Answer (score 0):

"Retrofit sending request asynchronously" which as @Tanis.7x mentioned, enqueue() is doing the asynchronous, so what could be a reason to put in AsyncTask ?  (async in async ?)

You can simply put all retrofit code out from AsyncTask and `onResponse` is the callback that is waiting for your request call to be back, so you can do any UI update inside of this callback.

Comment: I created LoginActivity by Android Studio, and it have TODO login section for sending login request. By default it located inside AsyncTask. I don't want to spend a lot of time for rewriting default activity structure and logic, so I just what to send request in the sequence inside the doInBackground

Comment: woah. I've just learned that AS is generating so much helpful code for LoginActivity !  That is insane.  What you said about without refactoring makes sense, thanks @neustart47 !

Answer (score 0):

Use retrofit `execute` method instead of the `enqueue` method.

Because in asynctask `doInbackground` method is already creating a thread to execute the code in background. No need to create it again using retrofit `enqueue`.