# can't get ArrayList outside of for loop in call.enqueue

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to get ArrayList data out of for loop from call.enqueue method in Retrofit.

how to access lists outside of call.enqueue mehtod?

Everything is working fine. When printing list size I'm getting value what I want. The only problem is i can't access values from outside of call.enqueue method.

```
private void getSchoolList() {
    final Call<List<DanceSchool>> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getDanceSchools();


    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<DanceSchool>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<DanceSchool>> call, Response<List<DanceSchool>> response) {
            if(!response.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, "Response Code: " + response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            List<DanceSchool> danceSchools = response.body();



            for(DanceSchool danceSchool:danceSchools){

                schoolNameList.add(danceSchool.getSchool_name());
                dayList.add(danceSchool.getDays());
                timingList.add(danceSchool.getSun_timing());
                contactNoList.add(danceSchool.getContact_no());
                addressList.add(danceSchool.getAddress());

            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<DanceSchool>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, "Failure: "+t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}
```

I want to access ArrayList outside of the call.enqueue method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way might be to declare a function,

```
void accessArrayList(ArrayList<DanceSchool> danceSchool){
    //do stuff with the values
}
```

and call it inside `call.enqueue`

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<DanceSchool>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(....) {
        ........
        List<DanceSchool> danceSchools = response.body();
        accessArrayList(danceSchools);
        .......
    }
}
```

Comment: You came in one minute earlier, so lets reward being a bit quicker, and having code out there first. Albeit in the end, we really had the same message ...

Answer (score 2):

The point is: right now you are making an **asynchronous** call. You are requesting some information, and when that information has been compiled and is ready **then** that `onResponse()` method is invoked. Only **then** that list can be populated from the incoming response body.

So, what you could do is: have another method in your enclosing class, like `updateList()`, and then simply call that method from within your `onResponse()` implementation.

Beyond that, you might want to turn your asynchronous call into a synchronous one. Then, instead, you use `execute()` to wait for the result to come in (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639232/retrofit-how-to-wait-for-response) for example). But you would still need to have a callback method to call.

Alternatively, you could have a **field** within the enclosing class, like

```
List<DanceSchool> danceSchools
...
private void getSchoolList() {
  final Call<List<DanceSchool>> call = ...    
  call.enqueue(new Callback<List<DanceSchool>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<DanceSchool>> call, Response<List<DanceSchool>> response) {
    ...
    danceSchools.addAll(response.body());
```

Comment: thanks for answering but I got my problem resolved.